# Why does "git push origin @" not work?

Tags: git, alias, git-push

We can push the head of a branch like below

```
$ git push origin HEAD
```

And, we can use `@` for alias of `HEAD`.

```
$ git show @
```

Then why does the below command gives me an error?

```
$ git push origin @
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in @
```

Comment: I guess because @ maps to a commit and not a head, so it cannot determine the remote name. `git push origin @:master` should work.

Comment: @eckes yet, '`@`' alone is supposed to be replaced by HEAD: https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba89f484e023827eca6ad44baf69af37dac4db3#diff-0e5e84388b3fb1c5edbec053379fbf1eR1025

Comment: What Git version did you try, @sangdol. There are some "fixes" docuemnted in 1.8.5 RelNotes

Comment: @VonC ah ok, never used that
(and I think `git push origin HEAD` is equal to `git push origin` with push.default=simple so one does not need the @ case.

Comment: @eckes I tried with 1.8.5.4. It's still not working on 2.0.4. And, `git push origin` is also not working on `push.default=simple`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although `@` can be used to specify `HEAD`, you first need `@` to be parsed as a ref. The syntax for `git push` takes a refspec, and in that context, `@` is given two different meanings, only one of which is a ref.

The syntax for a refspec in `git push` is `[+]<src>[:<dst>]`. `+` is optional. `:<dst>` is optional if it can be resolved from `<src>`.

`git push origin HEAD` works, because `HEAD` is treated as a very special case: `HEAD` is normally a symbolic ref to a specific branch, and `git push` resolves symbolic refs and selects `<dst>` based on the pointed-to branch name.

You can also have, for example, `git symbolic-ref MYMASTER refs/heads/master`, followed by `git push origin MYMASTER`.

`git push origin HEAD~0` fails, because it translates to `git push origin HEAD~0:HEAD~0`, and a remote refname `HEAD~0` is not valid, even though `HEAD~0` will necessarily always specify the exact same commit as `HEAD`.

`git push origin @` fails, because it translates to `git push origin @:@`, and a remote refname `@` is not valid, even though `@` will necessarily always specify the exact same commit as `HEAD`.

`git push origin @:HEAD` would almost work, if you have a remote branch named `HEAD`. This is not the special case where the refspec is simply `HEAD`, so this does not resolve `HEAD` based on any symbolic ref.

`git push origin @:master` does work.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation. What if git translates `@` to `HEAD` before `push` translates `@` to `@:@`? Is it not feasible?

Comment: @Sangdol Sure, it is feasible. If all fails, it could always be added as a special case. That would then be inconsistent with other commands, such as `git symbolic-ref @`, where it also doesn't work (and makes little sense to make it work). And of course, there's little benefit in making it work for `git push`: most people won't type any refspec at all. So I suspect that if it was considered at all, it was not considered necessary.